# AWS docs say that merge joins can be used for outer joins, but not full joins. Are those the same things?

Tags: amazon-redshift

Redshift [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c-the-query-plan.html) says:

> #### Merge Join
>
> Typically the fastest join, **a merge join is used for inner joins and
>   outer joins. The merge join is not used for full joins.**

But I've always read that full joins and outer joins are the same thing: rows from both tables are kept, regardless of if they exist in the other table.

Are they just referring to left outer joins and right outer joins as those that work for merge sort, while "outer join"s (full outer joins) do not?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good spot, perhaps the docs could be clearer. [You can submit a pull request for our docs if you feel motivated to do so.](https://github.com/awsdocs/amazon-redshift-developer-guide)

In this case, the doc means that a merge join is used when one table is the "primary" table, e.g, it will be used for `INNER JOIN`, `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN`, `RIGHT [OUTER] JOIN` but not used for `FULL [OUTER] JOIN` where rows from both side must be retained.